# Space between footer and bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I looked at the other questions to this topic but the answers doesn't help me. 
It's a little bit hard to explain but i'll try. So I have a footer:

```
#fußzeile{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e9e8e5;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried `overflow: hidden, height: 100%` etc.
I used margin-top to push the wrapper down then it works but if I minimize the site the gap is back again.. Position: absolute/relative doesn't work also..

Comment: You'll need to put this in a fiddle and it's not really clear what you're asking?

Comment: A simple google search for 'css sticky footer' will give you plenty of options for that

Comment: I used body{padding: 0px; margin: 0px} already.. doesn't work. I googled it and the options weren't the best so I decided to ask here.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle so that we can visualize the problem ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following in your css:

```
#fußzeile{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#fußzeile{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #e9e8e5;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xYqZE/)** is a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

this corrected it for me with 2 added lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is no content above the footer. You can try this Move the footer div outside any container (if it is contained in a container, make sure its a direct child to the html) and then make the POSITION : absolute;